# Need help with proving the existence of a subsequence in Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^1([0,1],\lambda)$ with respect to the $L^1$ norm. Prove or disprove that there exists a subsequence $f_{n_j}$ such that $f_{n_j}(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ for almost every $x\in[0,1]$ ($\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}$)

I tried a lot but couldn't go anywhere, any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What theorems do you know regarding convergence in $L^1$, convergence in measure, and subsequences converging almost everywhere?

Comment: @Michael, Do you mean like convergence in $L^1$ implies convergence in measure?

Comment: Yes, that is very useful here. Do you know any other results along these lines?

Comment: Or even corresponding results in probability?

Comment: @Michael, Sorry, I am new in measure theory.

Comment: Well, perhaps this is not a fair question then! =)

Comment: In the probability world, there is a theorem that says "convergence in probability implies there is a subsequence that converges with probability 1."

Comment: The idea is to find a subsequence of increasing positive integers $n[k]$ such that $\lambda\left(\left\{x \in [0,1]: |f(x)-f_{n[k]}(x)|>1/k\right\}\right) \leq 2^{-k}$.  Then try to bound the measure of the set of all points $x$ such that $|f(x)-f_{n[k]}(x)|\leq 1/k$ for all sufficiently large values of $k$.